# What is the best way to create html around hidden fields added to a panel?

Tags: c#, .net

I add these hidden input fields into a panel :

```
foreach (Object obj in Objects)
{
    HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
    hf.Value = "";
    hf.ID = "categoria" + obj.ID;
    panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Add(hf);
}
```

but, around each hidden fields, I need to add this code :

```
<div class="option-box"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option-box-item">&nbsp;</a>
    <span class="option-box-testo">Hello</span>
    <!-- HERE I NEED TO PUT THE HIDDEN FIELD i, so think to this whole option-box item into a cycle -->
</div>
```

I'd like to avoid to write `Literal` on the cs and add them into the panel.

What can you suggest to me?

Comment: must it be literally that, letter for letter, or must it just be functionally the same/similar?  If the former, just use a `LiteralControl`, if the latter, there are some actual choices/options.

Comment: no...should be only pure html text! around each hidden field, the one posted...

Comment: I didn't ask a yes or no question, so answer "no" doesn't tell me anything.  No matter what you do, the result is going to be HTML at the end of the day.  That's how web programs work.  When all is said and done, there really isn't anything else it *can* be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Repeater control, markup :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="catRep" runat="server" onitemcreated="catRep_ItemCreated">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="option-box"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option-box-item">&nbsp;</a>
      <span class="option-box-testo">Hello</span>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="hiddenPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>          
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code behind :

```
protected void catRep_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  Control placeHolder = e.Item.FindControl("hiddenPlaceHolder");
  if (placeHolder != null)
  {
    MyItemClass my = (MyItemClass)e.Item.DataItem;
    HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
    hf.Value = "";
    hf.ID = "categoria" + my.ID;
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(hf);
  }
}
```

Of course you will have to bind repeater with Objects list

Comment: Tried your simple code! But it doesnt print nothing (I just removed `MyItemClass my = (MyItemClass)e.Item.DataItem;` and put `hf.ID = "categoria_example";`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt print", markup will be rendered, ID would be autogenerated

Comment: No, the HTML code is not rendered. In fact, it doesnt enter on if (placeHolder != null). Looks as placeHolder is null :O

Comment: Copied and pasted your code. Rendering? Empty. Seems that it don't generate any code.

Comment: well I don't have clue, I tested code I posted in the first place and it works OK, try to debug, what control is e.Item, what child controls does it have, etc.

Comment: Are you doing this?! `catRep.DataSource = objects;
catRep.DataBind();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use HtmlGenericControl like so..

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Attributes.Add("class", "option-box");

HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a") { InnerText = "&nbsp;" };
a.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:void(0);");
a.Attributes.Add("class", "option-box-item");

HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span") { InnerText = "Hello" };
a.Attributes.Add("class", "option-box-testo");

div.Controls.Add(a);
div.Controls.Add(span);
div.Controls.Add(hf);
```

Comment: This is what I'd like to avoid, "html" in the .cs :)

Comment: Can you give to me an example of ListView?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this sort of thing over and over, you should probably look into making it a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) so you can simply code what you need and then reuse it without worrying about what needs to be around it.  At that point you could set the hidden field to be whatever you need it to be, and access it programmatically later.

Or, even better, consider if [Microsoft MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is appropriate and make something like this to function as a replaceable view in there.

Edit based on comment:
You're not terribly clear on precisely how this needs to be used, so this is a rough go at things where I'm making a lot of assumptions on your usage of the hidden field.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.ascx.cs" Inherits="stuff.test" %>
<div class="option-box"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option-box-item">&nbsp;</a>
    <span class="option-box-testo">Hello</span>
    <asp:label id="label1" runat="server" visible="false"/>
</div>
```

Then in the codebehind drop in:

```
    public Label HiddenField
    {
        get { return (Label)FindControl("label1"); }
    }
```

From there you can add as many of these controls, called whatever you please, in whatever you are using it in, then use a similar FindControl invocation (or put them in a NamingContainer if you need multiple invocations, see [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1313476.aspx) for an idea of how to do this.  After you have the user control where you're using it, you just have to do UserControl.HiddenField.Text to get the label you're looking for.

The biggest presumption this makes is that these hidden fields all have to be handled in general isolation - this is the impression your ForEach gave me since you appear to be handling each one similarly, but independently of one another.  If all these things have to be handled based on the values of one another, you're probably better off going with the Repeater suggestion.

Comment: Can you give a smart example on how this user control could be done?

Comment: @markzzz: Added as best I can but your question is a little confusing so I'm not sure if I got it right based on what you were asking.

Comment: In fact is not what I want :) Thanks anyway!